# Find the product of items in the list without using the multiplication sign

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new in python and I wrote code to have the product of items in a list without using the multiplication sign:

```
def witOutmultiply(some_list):
    first_num = some_list[0]
    result = 0
    for n in some_list[1:]:
        for i in range(n):
            result += first_num
        first_num = result
        result = 0
    return  first_num


q =[2,4,5,6,10,15]
print(witOutmultiply(q))
```

My question is: can I use comprehensions in this case, and can I get the result with just one loop? Thanks

Comment: No, I don't but its a challenge with friends

Comment: Don't you find it unethical to ask for help in a friendly challenge?

Comment: No , i do the challenge with my code the extra condition was optional and as I said I'm new in python and i want to learn by practice with multi tasks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use list comprehension, `sum`, and `range`, but no other builtin functions:

```
q = [2,4,5,6,10,15]

mult = q[0]
for n in q[1:]:
    mult = sum(mult for _ in range(n))
print(mult)
#36000
```

Comment: thank you very much your answer what i was looking for, appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer with no loop at all that satisfies your condition of "no multiplication sign." It is therefore very fast. The `reduce` function repeats an operation between members of an iterable, reducing it to a single value, while the `mul` function multiplies two numbers. The `1` at the end of the `reduce` function gives a reasonable value if the iterable (list) is empty. No multiplication sign in sight!

```
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce

def prod_seq(seq):
    """Return the product of the numbers in an iterable."""
    return reduce(mul, seq, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I appreciate your time to answer me

Comment: Can i ask you if we can do it with comprehensions without builtin funcitons

Comment: I'm not sure that using `operator.mul` is following the spirit of the "no multiplication operator" rule.

Comment: @HusseinAl-Obaidy: Could you be more specific as to what a "builtin function" is? Your sample code uses addition, which could be considered a builtin function.

Comment: @RoryDaulton really I appreciate your answer maybe i was not clear about what I need but your answer is quite awesome and you learn me new funciton in python

Answer (score 1):

Comprehensions are used to build data structures. A list comprehension builds a list, a dict comprehension builds a dict, etc. Since you want a single value rather than a data structure in your computation, there's no good reason to use a comprehension.

There probably are ways to avoid using two loops, but it's not going to be easy, since your outer loop does several operations, not just one. Most of the easy ways to avoid an explicit loop will just be hiding one or more loops in some function call like `sum`. I think that for your chosen algorithm (doing multiplication by adding), your current code is quite good and there's no obvious way to improve it.

Comment: I agree with you, but I'm reading about Comprehensions and just was curious if I can solve this with Comprehensions

Answer (score 1):

```
from numpy import prod
print(prod(q))
#36000
```